# Spring MVC use application scope level attribute instead of session scope level attribute

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In Spring MVC we can use

```
@SessionAttributes("variable")
```

and

```
model.addAttribute("variable", new Object());
```

Such that this variable once set is availabel to user session.

Now i want this variable to be set at application scope such that if `user 1` sets this attribute it will be available to all my users `user 2`, `user 3`, `user 4` etc.

and this variable will be used on my jsp page.
Please suggest.

Comment: set a bean into the web application context. You can do this by defining this bean in spring-servlet.xml. In your controller just autowire this bean and get the value there and set it to request. I guess this should do it. Hope this is clear.

Comment: Please Post some code as answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You can define one simple Pojo as Spring Bean Service to do.

```
@Service
public class MyVariable{

    private Object myVar;

    public Object getMyVar() {
        return myVar;
    }

    public void setMyVar(Object myVar) {
        this.myVar = myVar;
    }

}
```

Then, you can @Autowired this service in your @Controller and get it to anything.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean web application scope, then you need to set it in the `ServletContext` attributes. Because this isn't a common thing to do in web applications from a user perspective, Spring doesn't offer a shortcut. Instead, just retrieve the `ServletContext` either by injecting it into your `@Controller` or providing it as a parameter to a handler method and add the attribute

```
ServletContext ctx = ...;
ctx.setAttribute("name", new Object());
```

Note that there is a single `ServletContext` per web application. The `ServletContext` does not guarantee any atomicity, ie. it is not synchronized. You need to do that synchronization yourself, if required by the application.

Comment: since Spring controllers are singletons by default and object fields will be shared for all requests and sessions, why can't we use class variable with `private` modifier?

Comment: @tangobee That's effectively what you are doing by injecting the `ServletContext` and setting the attribute there. You might need access to the attribute in `Filter` and `Listener` instances that don't (normally) have access to Spring beans.