# Limiting a Java/JSP application to a certain number of hibernate queries

Tags: java, oracle, performance, hibernate, jsp

I'd like some help with coming up with an efficient solution to limit a Java/JSP application running on a tomcat server to a maximum number of simultaneous hibernate Oracle SQL queries.

Example: 
If the query limit is 3 then only 3 application users can trigger and run a particular query at the same time. If a 4th user comes along (and no other user has completed their query) then that user will be presented with a an alert that they'd have to wait first. Once a spot becomes available that user will be alerted.

Each time a user triggers a query I'd want to store an indicator of sorts to a file/database which would represent either all the users or just a count of the total queries being processed currently. 
Now, I know this may not be very efficient so I'm reaching out for help with this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Storing in file/db is not very efficient, it may add a slight overhead to the response. You should store the value in memory. You can store just one variable in the `session scope` of the user (You can store in `application scope` if you want to limit in application level). In that way you don't need to manage a common store like a Map where you have to reference using User Ids (case of per user limit).

The way you access these scope will vary based on the web framework you are using. Also, (let's say for per user limit)  You can increment the variable (say `currentQueryCount`) when you are about to do a hibernate query and decrement the same when query is done. On every request you can first check this variable if the limit exceeded, if so you can send error response.

Comment: I'm using the Spring Framework. Are there application scoped variables can be accessed and modified by all sessions? If one session modifies it that update is accessible to all other sessions?

Comment: please check this link. it explains two ways to address this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22574263/spring-mvc-use-application-scope-level-attribute-instead-of-session-scope-level . Also, please accept the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a connection pool? That would let you set a max number of connections and usually they provide a method to query the number of connections that are idle (which you could use for your alert).  See Apache's [DBCP](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) or [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html).

Comment: Yes, I am using one but that's not the solution I'm aiming for. I'd want to limit the amount of simultaneous queries for a particular query.